# Problema con XMLHttpRequest en archivo local

Tags: javascript, ajax

Estoy tratando de leer un archivo TXT con javascript por medio de un botón usando `addEventListener`.

Éste es mi código:

```
document.querySelector('#boton').addEventListener('click', extraerDatos);

function extraerDatos(){


    const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.open('GET', 'prueba.txt', true); 

    xhttp.send();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
            //console.log(this.responseText);
        documento.querySelector('#respuesta').innerHTML = this.responseText;
        }

    }
}
```

Y en Chrome me da este error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
>   'file:///C:/Users/Victor%20Alvarez/Desktop/COMP/leer/prueba.txt' from
>   origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests
>   are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome,
>   chrome-extension, https.

¿Qué debo hacer para que me permita leer el txt?

Comment: Hola Victor, te recomiento usar un servidor http simple. De lo contrario el protocolo file:/// te dará problemas.

Comment: Gracias, me adelanté a eso y usé http-server. ahora tengo este error: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Ahi ya no tienes un problema de CORS. Tienes que verificar que la URL sea la correcta, 404 indica que no lo es.

Comment: Ya accediendo a la ip del servidor intenté nuevamente y obtuve este:javas.js:15 Uncaught ReferenceError: documento is not defined
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhttp.onreadystatechange (javas.js:15)

Comment: documento no es un elemento existente,  existe es document, quitale la o.

Comment: Listo, con eso quedo. Muchas gracias a ambos.

Comment: Victor A. de nada,  considera añadir tu solucion al apartado de respuestas,  esta pregunta puede ayudarle a otras personas.

Comment: Además, te aconsejo usar un entorno de desarrollo en línea sin tener que instalar xampp ni nada en tu equipo (necesitas registrarte o enlazar con tu cuenta de github): https://gitpod.io/

Comment: Usaré gitpod.io para leer un json. En un momento publicaré la respuesta. Gracias

Answer (score 2):

El necesario usar un servidor HTTP pues, como decía [@Klaimmore](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/73136/klaimmore), el protocolo `file:///` dará problemas de [CORS (Intercambio de Recursos de Origen Cruzado)](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS).

Para instalar un servidor HTTP usé el paquete `http-server` de [NPM](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Npm).

Para ello instalé NPM: https://npmjs.com/get-npm

Después de descargarlo se ejecutan las instrucciones:

```
node -v
npm -v
```

Para verificar que estén instalados Nodejs y NPM.

Luego:

```
npm install http-server -g
```

Para montar el servidor y después hice un `cd [la ruta donde está el fichero]` con mis documentos `.js`, `.html` y demás y sobre esa ruta ejecuté `http-server` y la IP que me asigna será la que almacene mi html que lee el archivo TXT inicial.

Comment: He hecho un par de mejoras en tu respuesta para que la respuesta sea de mayor utilidad.